# How to use BDD to code complex data structures / data layers

Tags: tdd, bdd

I'm new to behavior-driven development and I can't find any examples or guidelines that parallel my current problem.

My current project involves a massive 3D grid with an arbitrary number of slots in each of the discrete cells. The entities stored in these slots have their own slots and, thus, an arbitrary nesting of entities can exist. The final implementation of the object(s) used will need be backed by some kind of persistent data store, which complicates the API a bit (i.e. using words like load/store instead of get/set and making sure modifying returned items doesn't modify the corresponding items in the data store itself). Don't worry, my first implementation will simply exist in-memory, but the API is what I'm supposed to be defining behavior against, so the actual implementation doesn't matter right now.

The thing I'm stuck on is the fact that BDD literature focuses on the interactions between objects and how mock objects can help with that. That doesn't seem to apply at all here. My abstract data store's only real "behavior" involves loading and storing data from entities outside those represented by the programming language itself; I can't define or test those behaviors since they're implementation-dependent.

So what can I define/test? The natural alternative is state. Store something. Make sure it loads. Modify the thing I loaded and make sure after I reload it's unmodified. Etc. But I'm under the impression that this is a common pitfall for new BDD developers, so I'm wondering if there's a better way that avoids it.

If I do take the state-testing route, a couple other questions arise. Obviously I can test an empty grid first, then an empty entity at one location, but what next? Two entities in different locations? Two entities in the same location? Nested entities? How deep should I test the nesting? Do I test the Cartesian product of these non-exclusive cases, i.e. two entities in the same location AND with nested entities each? The list goes on forever and I wouldn't know where to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between TDD and BDD is about language.  Specifically, BDD focuses on function/object/system behavior to improve design and test readability.

Often when we think about behavior we think in terms of object interaction and collaboration and therefore need mocks to unit test.  However, there is nothing wrong with an object whose behavior is to modify the state of a grid, if that is appropriate.  State or mock based testing can be used in TDD/BDD alike.

However, for testing complex data structures, you should use a Matchers (e.g. Hamcrest in Java) to test only the part of the state you are interested in.  You should also consider whether you can decompose the complex data into objects that collaborate (but only if that makes sense from an algorithmic/design standpoint).